# ion-backdrop height is not till ion-content

Tags: ionic3

[image]

I have a page with fab button and has backdrop which is displayed as soon as the fab opens. The issue is as the mobile height changes this backdrop does not reach the bottom of the ion-content.

```
 <ion-content>
  <div id="fab *ngIf="displayBack"></div>
  .....
</ion-content>

#fab-backdrop1 {
  background-color: black !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps u can put the ion-backdrop out of the ion-content;

```
<ion-backdrop></ion-backdrop>
<ion-content></ion-content>
```